# Why xcode's default build output is not in the project folder?

Tags: xcode, build, sdk, project

I'm really confused about why xcode not build its output into project folder defaultly, but in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder.

For a lot of software's output,  such as android studio's `.apk` file, and visual studio's `.exe` file are builded into project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes into *DerivedData* because that's where it goes. I don't know why you think you need to see it, but to do so is easy: locate the Product at the bottom of the Xcode window's project navigator and choose Show in Finder.

[image]

Comment: I know where the output is located. I just want to know, why the output is not in the project as others do such as android studio, visual studio. Xcode will need extra work to locate the output.